# When I enter text into a ComboBox the Suggestions are aligned right

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have the following Question, I have a `ComboBox` where `IsTextSearchEnabled` = True. If I enter a Letter the `Suggestions` are working correctly but they're align right.
[image: ComboBox Suggestions aligned right]

But the should be aligned left, so that I can see the start of the string and the end is cut off. How can I achieve that? I have the following code now:

```
<ComboBox Canvas.Left="803" Canvas.Top="48" Height="Auto" Name="cboKunde" Width="Auto" Padding="0" FontSize="22" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4"  
                      Margin="5,10,0,10" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ComboBoxStyleKey}}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                      IsEditable="True" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
                    </Style>
                </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>                    
            </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change IsEditable="True" to False and fix HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" then all items will be started like you want.

I've extracted template and the trick is this little piece:

```
<TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTextBox}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
```

By default first edit try in this textbox selects all its content and shows the end of selection, that is right part of it. So you need to deal with template.

Changing only HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" can't help for Editable ComboBox.

The quick fix is to handle selectionChanged at this TextBox and do whatever you want inside. For example - handler that restricts full selection

```
private void PART_EditableTextBox_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
        if (textBox.SelectionLength > 0 && 
            textBox.SelectionStart + textBox.SelectionLength == textBox.Text.Length) {
            textBox.SelectionLength = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you set `IsEditable="False"`, then `IsTextSearchEnabled` won't probably work, and the OP wants to have text search and suggestions.

Comment: IsEditable="False" does not affect suggestions

Comment: We really can only create assumptions about real usage in different situations. In my opinion all the problem is because author has limited screen space to show entire combobox value - if he can be sure that value is correct by several first symbols - why not to just limit represented values by that length or a few more without showing that lengthy text?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are setting `HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"` on your `ComboBox` in the Xaml.

If you would like to align your suggestions to the left I would suggest changing it to:

`HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"`

Answer (score 0):

Well, to achieve what you've ASKED, you only have to do this:

```
<ComboBox TextBoxBase.SelectionChanged="ScrollWhenSelected" />
```

And then in code-behind:

```
private void ScrollWhenSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var combo = sender as ComboBox;
    var textBox = combo.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", combo) as TextBox;

    if (textBox != null && textBox.SelectionLength > 0)
        textBox.ScrollToHome();
}
```

But you'll quickly find out that what you've asked is probably not what you want. Because this will make you unable to see what you're typing when the caret leaves the bounds of the TextBox, and it will also make text selection unreliable in general.

My suggestion is to either make your Combos bigger, or go with the default behavior and just make the scrolling when the Combo loses focus.

```
<ComboBox LostFocus="ScrollWhenSelected" />
```